# Can't call transcribed text from whisper to openai chatbot

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, openai-api, gpt-3, openai-whisper

This script takes input from microphone and transcribe the speech to text and pass the text to the gpt tex-davinci for generating response.

But the script is not generating any gpt response.

```
import openai
import gradio as gr

import whisper

import time

model = whisper.load_model("base")

prompt_input = ''

def transcribe(audio):
    global prompt_input
  
    # load audio and pad/trim it to fit 30 seconds
    audio = whisper.load_audio(audio)
    audio = whisper.pad_or_trim(audio)

    # make log-Mel spectrogram and move to the same device as the model
    mel = whisper.log_mel_spectrogram(audio).to(model.device)

    # detect the spoken language
    _, probs = model.detect_language(mel)
    print(f"Detected language: {max(probs, key=probs.get)}")

    # decode the audio
    options = whisper.DecodingOptions()
    result = whisper.decode(model, mel, options)
    prompt_input = result.text

gr.Interface(
    title='OpenAI Whisper ASR Gradio Web UI', 
    fn=transcribe, 
    inputs=[
        gr.inputs.Audio(source="microphone", type="filepath")
    ],
    outputs=[
        "textbox"
    ],
    live=True).launch(share=True)

openai.api_key = 'API_KEY'
openai.api_base = 'https://api.openai.com'

def ask_gpt(prompt, model):
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        engine=model,
        prompt=prompt,
        max_tokens=1024,
        n=1,
        stop=None,
        temperature=0.7
    )

    return response.choices[0].text.strip()

def main():
    model = 'text-davinci-003'
    while True:
        prompt = prompt_input
        if prompt.lower() == 'quit':
            break

        response = ask_gpt(prompt=f'User: {prompt}\nBot: ', model=model)
        print(f'Bot: {response}')
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am using the openai whisper ASR [web app](https://github.com/petewarden/openai-whisper-webapp) for speech-to-text and gpt text-davinci for generating response.
Also, I am running it in Google Colab.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To debug, I suggest you modify your function `ask_gpt` so that it returns the raw response.

For instance:

```
    def ask_gpt(prompt, model):
        response = openai.Completion.create(
            engine=model,
            prompt=prompt,
            max_tokens=1024,
            n=1,
            stop=None,
            temperature=0.7
        )
    
        return response
```

You may then examine what this function returns, and in particular the code response, the message, etc: the API usually responds with an "error" (or other) field explaining what happens.

```
result = ask_gpt('What is the meaning of life', model)
```

And then look at the values of `result.response_code` and `result.json()`. In the latter, you may find useful info on what happens.

If the response object doesn't have these attributes or methods, it may have others with different names, so feel free to explore this response to understand this structure.

By the way, I also suggest you use 'gpt-3.5-turbo' model instead of davinci: it is 10 times cheaper ($0.002 / 1K token instead of $ 0.020) and as efficient, as OpenAI say themselves: "ChatGPT models are optimized for dialogue. The performance of gpt-3.5-turbo is on par with Instruct Davinci." (source: https://openai.com/pricing#language-models)

Once that you found why your function doesn't return the expected result and fixed it, you can write another function that takes the result of the one above and parse its content:

```
def extract_result(response):
   return response.choices[0].text.strip()
```

So in your main you'll have:

```
response = ask_gpt(prompt, model)
result = extract_result(response)
```

Comment: I am new to programming, so can you explain more what to do or provide some snippets.

Comment: Yes, I've edited my initial answer.

Comment: I found the issue. The text davinci is working good. But the transcribed result from whisper is not correctly passed to the input of Text davinci that is why text davinci is not generating response. But I don't know how to fix this

Comment: Could you elaborate, and show your code and outputs? What do you mean by "the transcribed result from whisper is not correctly passed", what happens in your code?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved. But I don't know exactly how. I got help from the fellow Discord user, he figured that:

> the issue is within your while True statement, it errors because you are sending a request on start which has no audio attached. As seen in the attachment, I stopped it doing that and it responded with what I said using whisper.

So I modified the while true statement like this:

```
def main():
    
    model = 'text-davinci-003'
    while True:
        if prompt_input:
            prompt = prompt_input
            if prompt.lower() == 'quit':
                break

            response = ask_gpt(prompt=f'User: {prompt}\nBot: ', model=model)
            print(f'Bot: {response}')
            
            prompt_input = ''  # Reset the prompt input after generating the response
```

But it still showed the error.

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'prompt_input' referenced before assignment

So I added the `global prompt_input` in the `main()` function:

```
def main():
    global prompt_input
    model = 'text-davinci-003'
    while True:
        if prompt_input:
            prompt = prompt_input
            if prompt.lower() == 'quit':
                break

            response = ask_gpt(prompt=f'User: {prompt}\nBot: ', model=model)
            print(f'Bot: {response}')
            
            prompt_input = ''  # Reset the prompt input after generating the response
```

And then it worked.

Also thanks to @S_Crespo for your help.